# Sorting/Ordering in Descending order while Pivoting using spark.table command

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am using `spark.table` command and in it `pivot` command to pivot my data based on quarters using the below -

```py
spark.table("GSCH.TABLE"). \
    filter("source='ALL' yearmonth == 'AUGUST'"). \
    groupBy("dim_value"). \
    pivot("qtr"). \
    sum("percentage"). \
    sort("dim_value"). \
    show(100,false)
```

I am trying to sort the data as i want the quarters to be displayed in descending order and the sort command is not helping with the above command.

Data Currently i am getting

| FY2023-Q1 | FY2023-Q2 | FY2023-Q3 | FY2023-Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76565 | 123445 | 764644 | 91882 |
| 87474 | 73755 | 8736465 | 94959 |

I want the Data to be displayed in Descending order of Quarter -

| FY2023-Q4 | FY2023-Q3 | FY2023-Q2 | FY2023-Q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91882 | 764644 | 123445 | 76565 |
| 94959 | 8736465 | 73755 | 87474 |

How should i sort it using the `spark.table` command which i mentioned at the top?

Answer (score 1):

you could sort the column names first and then apply a select with the reordered columns, for example:

```
val df = spark.table("GSCH.TABLE").filter("source='ALL' yearmonth == 'AUGUST'").groupBy("dim_value").pivot("qtr").sum("percentage")
val orderedColumns = df.columns.sorted.reverse
val reorderedDf = df.select(orderedColumns.head, orderedColumns.tail: _*)
reorderedDf.show()
```

Comment: @ajcjsbx 

FY2023-Q4|FY2023-Q3|FY2023-Q2|FY2023-Q1 are not column names .
Its the values of COLUMN - qtr


which is used in the spark.table command .pivot("qtr")

so i want those values to appear in descending order for the column qtr which i am not able to achive using the spark.table command